# Is a 8 to 1 MUX transparent?

Tags: microcontroller, multiplexer

I want to detect a total of 32 inputs voltages. I plan on using the Atmega32, where the output of the MUX is connected to the ADC pin of the atmega32.

I will be detecting these voltages using 5 8 to 1 MUX (74LS151), as shown below. The s0,s1,s2,s3, and s4 will be controlled by the atmega32. My question is let's say if there is a voltage of 4.1V present at the input of the first MUX and I then set the appropriate pins to select this pin, will I read the 4.1V or will I read something closer to 5V? HEnce the transparent but of the question

[image]

Comment: You don't say what you are actually trying to do, but if you're trying to mux an analog voltage to an (for instance) ADC take a look at the CD74HC4067 or similar...

Comment: 74151 won't, but there are analog MUXes that will ... one of CD4051/2/3 or 74HC4051/2/3 is an 8:1 analog mux (despite being part of a logic family!)

Comment: Joey, you actually have all you need from the comments and answers here. What you appear to want is a single-pole multi-way analog switch (an SPnT) which has near infinite impedance to all the throws except for the selected one, where it has "low" impedance, instead. MOSFETs are much more like resistors that can be turned on and off and they fit this better, if designed well. This is what an analog switch IC does for you. But details matter in selecting an appropriate one. So I'm not bothering to contribute to the already useful answers here until/unless you write more details.

Answer (score 2):

The 74LS151 is a non-transparent mux, which performs a digital multiplexing function and then drives digital outputs.

The datasheet states that 2.0 V is the guaranteed HIGH voltage for all inputs, so a voltage of 4.1 V is safely within the "high" output range for TTL. However, its output voltage won't be guaranteed to go up to 5 V without a pull-up (as it's a TTL-style output, rather than a CMOS-style one).

Answer (score 2):

The 74LS151 is a DIGITAL MUX.  That means that you will not read a voltage that is in any way proportional to the input voltage on the selected input.  If the input is above the threshold voltage (Vih) for the input you will see a logic "1" out (i.e. Voh) on the output.  If the voltage is below Vil, you will see a "0" or Vol.  Other voltages between these two input levels will produce an indeterminate output.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated you have chosen a digital MUX, what you instead need is an analog one for instance [this one](https://www.digikey.se/product-detail/en/vishay-siliconix/DG408LEDY-T1-GE3/DG408LEDY-T1-GE3CT-ND/5994114).